# javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes : issue when try to save an empty field

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jpa

I have a form In which I need to save an object in the database. But I don't need to save this object with a **changeDate** attribute null so that I marked It as `@notNull` in the model .

the problem is when I click on save button and this field is empty it saved as null in the DB and this error appears.

Please I need your help to resolve this problem when I try to save a null field !

> 12:02:25,836 ERROR [stderr] (default task-14)
>   javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for
>   classes [xxx.model.model] during persist
>   time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ] 12:02:25,836 ERROR
>   [stderr] (default task-14) List of constraint violations:[
>   12:02:25,836 ERROR [stderr] (default task-14)
>     ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null',
>   propertyPath=ChangeDate, rootBeanClass=class
>   xxx.model.model,
>   messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
>   12:02:25,836 ERROR [stderr] (default task-14) ]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Maybe field/variable ChangeDate is null? But we need more info, as @FatemehAbdollahei explains.

Comment: @fatameh thank you :)

Comment: javax.validation is nothing to do with JPA, and everything to do with the Bean Validation API. But you haven't tagged that, and have tagged JPA ...